# Stretching/distorting a background image from a single point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Usually when an image is being resized in javascript or css3(using background-size), it will stretch an image from the center point.  I need an image to be stretched and distorted from a single point that could be anywhere.  It's going to be dynamic so I don't want to resort to using separate images.

Here's a pic that illustrates what I mean:
[image]

Hopefully there's an answer out there!

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question would be easier to follow if you embedded your image, rather than just linking to it. (Also, this means that if the picture is ever removed from Flickr, the question will still make sense).

Comment: Thanks for tip and greeting!  Btw, I just tried adding an image to my post but apparently the site prevents newbies like me from posting images, lol....  EDIT: okay, now they let me post it!

Comment: Heh. My bad for not knowing that. As long as the edit is approved, it does allow me to do it for you though. Hopefully this will make the question more useful if someone stumbles across it in future.

Comment: @JcFx: already added.  BTW, Chewster, "skew" might be what you wanted, but that "point" stretch is not a "skew"; it's something else.

Comment: @JayC - tripping over each other. I'll leave you to it...

Comment: Oh didn't realize you guys could do that, thanks!  I thought the change just took effect now, lol

@ JayC: You're right, it's not exactly a skew, but that term would've been better for helping me find the answer.  The canvas example that was posted is probably what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options to achieve this effect.

The "correct" way would be to use canvas to draw the image: [Skewing images individually using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253091/skewing-images-individually-using-canvas)

Another way would be to fake the effect using the CSS transform skew.
http://developerdrive.com/demo/skewing_elements/skewing_elements.html

You would do this inside an element with "overflow: hidden" to make it look like a background image.

Comment: Thanks!!  Skew is probably the term I should have been using.  Haven't explored html5 canvas much, but looks like that's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

It's not even clear to me what you want from the image you're linking too.  Do you want it distorted or not?  And is the distortion uniform?

I'm going to guess whatever you're doing can be approximated by drawing an ever decreasing set of (or maybe rectangles) clipped from the center of a some image and drawing them onto a "canvas" (think generic term not html5 term) given new coordinates for the center of each clipping.  There may be a faster way to draw this than redrawing parts of the image multiple times, it's just how I visualize it possibly working.. at least maybe in some mathematical sense.